# Better way to interpret user text input

Tags: java, android, logic, nlp

I have a Text Box in my app and the user can input anything. I am creating a controller which interprets some of the commands based on the keywords.

The user has an option of either setting a password or not. And depending on that, my interpreter will either expect a password or not.

For example, if a Password is set and user enters: "password1 show list". 
The interpreter checks for password in the first word, then next for the command(show) and then the argument(list).

If password not set, user enters "show list" and the interpreter understands.

My current code is:

```
// 'words' is a String array which contains the user input.

if (passwordEnabled()==true) {

    if (words[0].contentEquals(getPassword())
                    && words[1].contentEquals("show")
                    && words[2].contentEquals("list")) {

        // Perform action

    }
}
else {

    if (words[0].contentEquals("show")
                    && words[1].contentEquals("list")) {

        // Perform action

    }

}
```

My question is, is there a more efficient/better way to process commands? I am sure mine is a very crude method of doing it.

Comment: enum constants and switch cases is another way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to design the "language" based system, where you ask commands, you should think about two possible approaches based on the system complexity:

- building the finite automa of your system. Your if statements are the very basic form of such structure, but definind this as an actual automa, where you have states, and commands that moves you to the another state - is a very clean and generic approach.
- building a grammar + interpreter/compiler. Defining correct commands as grammatical (+compiler) rules would give you much more power in expressing possible commands and actions.

Of course these are not alternating solutions - building a grammar for the language is a very broad thing, and should be used to parse the command, while finite state automa serves as the internal memory and the definition of possible actions.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information. I am doing my research but could you point me to some resources regarding this? I am pretty new to this topic.

Comment: grammars are the basic tools in at least two disciplines: NLP and Compilers, both of which have very nice itroduction courses avaliable at the MOOC platforms. Compilers: http://www.class-central.com/mooc/328/coursera-compilers , NLP: http://www.class-central.com/mooc/307/coursera-natural-language-processing . Also automata have nice course there: http://www.class-central.com/mooc/376/coursera-automata

Answer (score 2):

Your way (or any grammar-based approach) is OK if users can remember the syntax of the commands.

If you want to understand the users when they express their intent with unrestricted, natural language, you need to do some [Natural Language Understanding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_understanding).

Something like Wit (http://wit.ai) may do the job for you. It's based on machine learning. It converts free text sentences into JSON with the user intent and normalized parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Building a grammar or finite automa are right ways of doing that, agreed.

If you want an easy way, you  may simplify your code like that:

```
if (passwordEnabled()) {
    if  (! words.get(0).contentEquals(getPassword()))
    {
        // wrong password
        return;
    }
    words.remove(0); // skip password
}

if (words.get(0).contentEquals("show")
                && words.get(1).contentEquals("list")) {

    // Perform action

}
```

Suppose you use `ArrayList` for `words`.